# HTML5 application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I wish tho host my HTML5 application on Heroku. But I must choose one of the platforms (Java, Python, Node.js, etc) for my app. How can I run my application under Node.js? I have been able to create and deploy a simple Node.js app in Heroku however I am yet to figure out how can I merge my HTML5 app into this Node.js app.

I hope I make sense.

Tanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"HTML5 app" is very non-descriptive and generic. If you mean an entirely client-side HTML application with no real backend logic, than that's trivial with node.js on heroku. If you put this in the root of your git repo in a file called server.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.use(express.static('app'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Then put all of your HTML5 app in a directory called 'app' and node will serve it up.

Also in the root of your repo you'll need a Heroku Procfile with the following:

```
web: node server.js
```

Finally, you'll also want a package.json in the root of your repo so that Heroku can install your dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "description": "My application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ruby as well. rack based app [Heroku rack based app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack)

You need to create a config.ru file and put your HTML content into public folder

Here are more details about creating a static site based on rack app. [Creating Static Sites in Ruby with Rack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby)

Hope this helps!